# When would I use enterprise search over CAML?

Tags: search

For instance, if I just want to search for an employee and all of their colleagues and supervisors, would I use FAST search, CAML or LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing a search for people against the API then it should be very quick.  Once you have a username it there are already methods in place to grab their colleagues, and supervisor.

If the content is not in the user profiles, but rather a contact list, then it might be better to interact with the specific list than the do a search against all content.  CAML versus Linq is really just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the location of the employee information, the context in which your code runs and the composition of your farm.

The best way to determine the answers to performance questions is to test, test and test.

Comment: Let's assume the information is ported from Active Directory and there are custom lists providing meta data... is there no hard and fast rule for searching these values?